# Wordpress custom posts page coming blank

Tags: wordpress, posts

I am new to wordpress

I created a theme and created new static page as home page

Now wanted to add blog page and for this I created another page, named it as blog and then marked it as "posts page" in settings >> reading

If I don't do this then I can see header and footer of the page but if I do the above then it shows blank page without anything

1. Why it shows completely blank page?
2. How can I relate posts with it?

On doing

define('WP_DEBUG', true);

I get errors like below

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in D:\wamp\www\project\wp-content\plugins\exec-php\exec-php.php on line 22

And after removing these errors, still its blank page

Should I use any other plugin?

All website is complete just blog page needs to be created

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change your name from `blog` to other name such as `article`, `blogs`, `journal`... which related to the intention of your site because there's probably a conflict happen in naming convention of `Wordpress` or your theme here.

Comment: I tried this but haven't worked. If I change theme then it works properly... means there is an issue with the theme that I developed

In my theme only following files are getting used rest are blank:

1. header.php
2. footer.php
3. style.css
4. page.php
5. functions php

functions.php just has following two lines

remove_filter( ‘the_content’, ‘wpautop’ );
remove_filter( ‘the_excerpt’, ‘wpautop’ );

I have created various pages in wordpress admin and placed text in posts

I have used exec-php

All posts are fetched and displayed in pages

Comment: Is it possible that I create a separate theme for blog.... if I create that how it will be used, as only one theme can be used?